# Why is there an error when attempting to initialize a 3D array because it is not an array type and the range does not exist?

Tags: arrays, error-handling, 3d, initialization, cplex

Actually, I want to input 14 matrices as a 3D array. For that, I have entered the first matrix, and  then the other 13 matrices are typed below the first matrix.

The data file code is given as

```
SheetConnection excel1("soc3d.xlsx");
array from SheetRead(excel1,"Sheet1!B2:CW337");
```

The code for the model file is

```
int nb=14;
int t=24;
int nv=100;
range nbus=1..nb;
range tavail =1..t;
range nport=1..nv;
float array=...;
float soc[nbus][tavail][nport]=item(array,<nbus,tavail,nport>).value;
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [write3D](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/write3Darraybis.mod) / [read3D](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/read3Darraybis.mod) example

**write:**

```
int maxA=2;
int maxB=3;
int maxC=4;

range A=1..maxA;
range B=1..maxB;
range C=1..maxC;


dvar int X[A][B][C];

subject to
{
forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==a*b*c;
}

range r=1..maxA*maxB*maxC;

int result[i in r]=
X[(i-1) div (maxB*maxC)+1][((i-1)-maxB*maxC*((i-1) div (maxB*maxC))) div maxC+1][(i-1) mod maxC+1];
```

**read:**

```
int maxA=2;
int maxB=3;
int maxC=4;

range A=1..maxA;
range B=1..maxB;
range C=1..maxC;

range r=1..maxA*maxB*maxC;

int input[r]=...;
int input3D[a in A][b in B][c in C]=input[(a-1)*maxB*maxC+(b-1)*maxC+c-1+1];   



dvar int X[A][B][C];

subject to
{
 forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==input3D[a][b][c];
}

assert forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==a*b*c;
```